# unattended-upgrades write mail to file and run script

Tags: server, unattended-upgrades, telegram

Is there a way to instruct unattended-updates to write the update mails to a file?

And second, is there a way to run a custom script every time it upgrades the system?

I have a telegram monitoring bot running on my server, and I actually don't want to receive the messeges per mail but per telegram. These should be containing which packages were upgraded.